# Why do I get an unexpected result when using socket.readUnsignedInt() in Adobe Air?

Tags: sockets, air, adobe

I have two air applications that communicate with each other using sockets.

Code on app 1

```
socket.writeUnsignedInt(4);
```

Code on app 2

```
socket.readUnsignedInt();
```

I am expecting the result of readInt() to be '4' (the int I sent) but I get '262144'

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: 262144 in hex is 00 04 00 00 - perhaps your stream is out-of-sync, i.e. you read too few bytes from it before `readUnsignedInt()` call?

Comment: @Code Painters I am not reading any bytes from the stream before `readUnsignedInt()` should I be? I have found that I always have 62 bytes available in the stream when I read the int.

Comment: Well, you've posted only a single statement, thus I can't tell what's happening before. Perhaps you could share the whole snippet?

Comment: @Code Painters Thank you!!! I was leaving bytes in the stream by mistake. If you make your first comment an answer I will accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: Done, answer posted, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 262144 value in hex is `00 04 00 00`, most likely your stream is out-of-sync, i.e. you read too few bytes from it before `readUnsignedInt()` call.